# Why does VS code output differ from online compiler

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, time.h

I wrote a test to solve a problem I am having with a program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    double time;

    clock_t begin, end;


    begin = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
    
    }
    end = clock();


    time = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%lf", time);
}
```

the output for the online C compiler:

```
0.000002
```

the output for VS code:

```
0.000000
```

can someone explain why VS code is rounding to 0?

Comment: Did you compile these programs with compiler optimizations turned on or off? If they were turned on, then the compilers probably optimized the loop away, because the loop has no observable effects.

Comment: The two compilers you are using may have a different clock precision. Also, you may want to increase the precision when printing the `double` using `printf`, for example by writing `printf("%10lf", time);`.

Comment: What makes you think that the VS code is not rounding correctly?  Surely you are not assuming that the code's runtime will be identical in the two environments?  Try scaling up the result to units of milliseconds or even microseconds.

Comment: The time between two clock ticks under windows is, as far as I can remember, ~15 ms, so if your work does take much shorter time than 15ms, then you may not see any changes in the return value of `clock()`, Or if you start time measurement right before a clock tick, you may measure a runtime of 15ms. Oh, and if your loop doesn't get optimized out as @AndreasWenzel explained, counting to 100 is still extremely fast, I would guess ~50-100 nano-seconds. Why the runtime on the online system was dog slow (2000 ns), cant be answered without knowing the exact system.

Comment: Apart from you never can fully trust such measurements. Times can slightly differ due to different underlying architectures and especially with longer loops – with just 100 runs it's not too likely – context switches might occur more often on one system than on the other due to differing number of threads running on the core or different scheduling strategies (configured differently or different OS). Other effects like interrupts occurring play a role, too. Such effects can result in slightly differing results even if you run the code on one and the same machine multiple times.

Comment: You can `printf` the `begin`, `end` and `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` values with full precision, and verify for yourself that the rounding is correct in both cases.

Comment: do something inside the for loop that gets printed (before or after the `end = clock();`). Preferably something the compiler can't statically calculate. Use the value of `begin`. Compilers are smart these days.